# Page shows empty space when the flag/close popups placed at the extreme right/bottom side

Tags: discussion, bug, status-declined, user-interface, popups

In Stack Overflow review pages, when we closing or flagging a post a popup will appear something like:

[image: Normal]

When I drag that popup to extreme right, the page is showing a horizontal scroll bar:

[image: With Horizontal scroll bar]

If I scroll the page to left using that horizontal scroll bar the page shows white spaces:

[image: Issue]

Same issue happens when we place the popup to extreme bottom also:

[image: Another issue]

Comment: so don't move it there...

Comment: @JanDvorak: I won't do that again :) But it won't fix that bug.

Comment: It is not _really_ a bug @MidhunMP ... That is just how dialogs work

Comment: @qwertynl: Thanks for the info dude, I wasn't aware of this. Thanks :)

Comment: You report this as a bug, but don't tell us what the expected behavior should be?

Comment: @Oded: I expect that, there is no issue with left side or top side, so the similar should be for other two sides.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A man goes to The Doctor one day and says:

> My arm hurts when I do **this**

The Doctor responds:

> So don't do that

The same applies here.

Comment: Why he said like that, instead of giving treatment/medicine ? :) If you say to him that you have pain in your teeth while chewing, what could be his answer ( not chew probably) ? :)

Comment: The **this** implies some random movement that a person does not usually make :-P

Comment: Yeah. that's true :) but it won't fix the issue permanently :)

Answer (score 2):

"A man goes to The Doctor .. So don't do that"
The same answer could apply to all bugs.
"When I click upvote it doesn't work .. Well don't vote..".

But the point here is it's not a bug, nor status-by-design, it's the way the internet works and in fact this site handles that quite well I think.

The popup box when you click "flag" is site content, and it can be moved around. The fact it can be moved outside the standard site dimensions (X or Y) could return a few things:

1. The box *doesn't* produce a horizontal or vertical scroll, as such
   you "lose" part of the content (the box) out of the site into no mans land and
   you cannot get to it fully. In fact you cannot get to it at all if you "throw" the flag box, thus needing the horizontal scroll to retrieve it.
2. The box *does* produce a horizontal or vertical scroll, and as such
   you do not lose any part of what is actual site content as the site
   page dimensions grow with you moving the box.

When you think about it, 2. is more desirable by far, and more logical that actual site content changes the page dimensions as a part of the site. Rather than just disappearing as if it's suddenly not classed as site content.

In fact, if you are moving the box out of the way so you can access site content while deliberating over which flag to choose, then it changing the page dimensions is better still, as then you can move it right out of the way without losing it, and scroll to get it back if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The area you describe as being empty actually contains the dialogue you just moved there. As such this seems like a case of a very well written page behaving exactly as it should under surprising circumstances.  As such it very much isn't a bug

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212473/page-shows-empty-space-when-the-flag-close-popups-placed-at-the-extreme-right-bo/212489#comment683787_212473 :-P